# Call ViewController inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a ViewController wich have a UItableView.
Inside every cell in this TableView I have a subview.

In the first row of my TableView I have a subview that contains 2 buttons.
I want that when one of those buttons are pressed, my UINavigationController pushes my secondViewController on the screen.

But nothing happens, I don't get any errors, just don't happen!
I already try everything I now, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code at my AppDelegate.m

```
firstViewController * firstView = [firstViewController new];
UINavigationController * navViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstView];

self.window.rootViewController = navViewController;
```

In my firstViewController I have my TableView:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_actionBar];
}
else {

    for (UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    _feed = [[Y_feedViewController sharedFeed]getViewWithThisInfo:[_arrayOfFeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_feed];
}

return cell;
}
```

So, the Buttons are in my _actionBar (that I add as a subview in my first row), and when I press the Button01 I want to call my secondViewController

Man, I already try everything, but can't work with this.
I already try to call the pushViewController: from my _actionBar, my TableViewController, my firstViewController, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: This previous code is not enough for helping you to solve your issue, we will need the implementation of your `_actionBar` and the implementation of the `button inside your _actionbar` (especially the method which is called while `TouchUpInside`)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you are assigning an action to the buttons in _ActionBar. I think it would be easier and cleaner to use two different cell types, one of which has the buttons in it (rather than adding a subview in code). Just dequeue the one you want based on the indexPath. When you dequeue the one for the first row, add the action and target for your buttons (with the target being the view controller).